# Where Clause with OR in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I write a where clause where I have a where argument that can take multiple options. For example,

```
User.where(name: "Jason" OR name: "Bob")
```

Although I know that isn't the correct syntax, what is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't have a console to hand to check, I'm pretty sure it's:

```
User.where(name: ["Jason", "Bob"])
```

Comment: Confirmed your syntax in a console. `User.where('name = ? or name = ?', 'Jason', 'Bob')` will also work.

Comment: I was so close. I had `:` instead of `=`. Thanks for the other option.

Comment: Just as a side note, squeel (https://github.com/ernie/squeel) provides pretty neat stuff for that kind of queries

Answer (score 0):

I'm always late to the party...

```
friends = User.where(:name => ["Jason", "Bob"])
```

(Rails 4.0.0)